# Is there a MySQL Statement for this or are multiple statements needed?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with MLSNumber, ListingContractDate, CloseDate.

I want to summarize the activity grouped my month starting with the current month and going back to January 2000.

I have this statement which summarizes the ListingContractDate by month.

```
SELECT COUNT(MLSNumber) AS NewListings, DATE_FORMAT(ListingContractDate,'%M %Y')
FROM Listings
WHERE Neighbourhood = 'Beachside' 
  AND ListingContractDate >= '2000-01-01' 
GROUP BY YEAR(ListingContractDate), MONTH(ListingContractDate)
ORDER BY ListingContractDate DESC
```

The two problems with this statement are if there is nothing found in a specific month it skips that month, and I would need to return a 0 so no months are missing, and I am not sure how to get the same count on the CloseDate field or if I just have to run a 2nd query and match the two results up by month and year using PHP.

Comment: A [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com), please?

Comment: See fiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8b34e/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An exceptionally useful item to have is a "tally table" which simply consists on a set of integers. I used a script found [HERE](http://www.solomonson.com/content/how-create-tally-table-mysql) to generate such a table.

With that table I can now LEFT JOIN the time related data to it as shown below:

```
set @startdt := '2000-01-01';

SELECT COUNT(MLSNumber) AS NewListings, DATE_FORMAT(T.Mnth,'%M %Y') 
FROM (
      select
            tally.id
          , date_add( @startdt, INTERVAL (tally.id - 1) MONTH ) as Mnth
          , date_add( @startdt, INTERVAL tally.id MONTH ) as NextMnth
      from tally
      where tally.id <= (
          select period_diff(date_format(now(), '%Y%m'), date_format(@startdt, '%Y%m')) + 1
            )
     ) t
LEFT JOIN Temp On Temp.ListingContractDate >= T.Mnth and Temp.ListingContractDate < T.NextMnth
GROUP BY YEAR(T.Mnth), MONTH(T.Mnth) 
ORDER BY T.Mnth DESC
```

Logc,

- define a stating date
- calculate the number of months from that date until now (using
  PERIOD_DIFF + 1)
- choose that number of records from the tally table
- create period start and end dates (tally.Mnth & tally.NextMnth)
- LEFT JOIN the actual data to the tally table using

> Temp.ListingContractDate >= T.Mnth and Temp.ListingContractDate < T.NextMnth

- group and count the data

see [this sqlfiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fc6832/3)